# Hiding C struct definition

Tags: c, oop, struct, compiler-errors, data-hiding

Here is my setup:

In public.h:

```
#ifndef PUBLIC_H_
#define PUBLIC_H_

#include "func.h"

/*extern typedef struct _my_private_struct PRIVATE_;*/
typedef struct _my_private_struct PRIVATE_; /* Thanks to larsmans and Simon Richter */
#endif
```

In struct.h

```
#ifndef STRUCT_H_
#define STRUCT_H_

struct _my_private_struct {
    int i;
};
#endif
```

In func.h:

```
#ifndef FUNC_H_
#define FUNC_H_
#include "struct.h"

/* typedef struct _my_private_struct PRIVATE_; */
extern PRIVATE_ * get_new(int);
#endif
```

In func.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "func.h"

PRIVATE_ * get_new(int i)
{
    PRIVATE_ *p = (PRIVATE_ *) malloc(sizeof(PRIVATE_));
    if (p == NULL) return NULL;

    p->i = i;

    return p; 
}
```

In main.c:

```
#include "public.h"

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    PRIVATE_ *p = get_new(2);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile those file with GCC I'm getting this error:

OLD COMPILE ERROR

> multiple storage classes in declaration specifiers

COMPILE ERROR AFTER EDIT

> expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm', or '__attribute__' before '*' token

Can someone help me out/explain why I'm getting this and how to fix it?

Comment: What's the point of `extern typedef`??

Comment: There is a ';' missing after the typedef.

Comment: @Kerrek SB The reason for `extern typedef` in `public.h` is I want to define the type and definition in another file. Do you think that causes compile error?

Comment: @wildplasser Thank you for pointing that out. I fixed them. I typed everything instead of copy and paste. Sorry for that mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other answers cover your problem pretty well. However, allow me to add to them and answer your latest comment:

> I'm getting compile error: in public.h: redefinition of typedef PRIVATE_...

While the error is self-explanatory it's probably less clear why that's happening. Consider what happens when you include public.h:

```
#include "struct.h"
#include "func.h"
typedef struct _my_private_struct PRIVATE_;
```

If you trace through this and fully expand the preprocessor, this is what you'll get:

```
// struct.h
struct _my_private_struct
{
    int i;
};

// func.h
typedef struct _my_private_struct PRIVATE_;
extern PRIVATE_ * get_new(int);

// public.h
typedef struct _my_private_struct PRIVATE_;
```

It should now be obvious why you're running into problems. Without the typedef in func.h, your `get_new` prototype fails because it hasn't seen `PRIVATE` yet. OTOH, if you leave the typedef in you've defined it twice.

Also, it looks like you're trying to keep that structure private from other code and modules. Even if you do fix the build errors you haven't really achieved that encapsulation. Consider this:

```
int main()
{
    PRIVATE_ *p = get_new(2);
    p->i = 1337;        // HAHA, I just modified your private i.
                        // what are you going to do about it?
}
```

If you want data privacy in C consider an opaque pointer design. I recommend restructuring your source like this:

```
// public.h
#ifndef PUBLIC_H_
#define PUBLIC_H_

#include "func.h"

#endif
```

---

```
// func.h
#ifndef FUNC_H_
#define FUNC_H_

struct PRIVATE_NOT_ACCESSIBLE;
typedef struct PRIVATE_NOT_ACCESSIBLE myint_t;

// declare your struct methods here
myint_t* get_new(int);
// ..

#endif
```

---

```
// func.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "func.h"

// define this only with functions 
// that's suppose to work with its internal data
struct PRIVATE_NOT_ACCESSIBLE
{
    int i;
};

myint_t * get_new(int i)
{
  // ...
}
```

Now if you try this:

```
#include "public.h"

int main()
{
    myint_t *p = get_new(2);
    p->i = 1337;            // Aw, doesn't work anymore :(
}
```

**Edit:** To answer the OP's comment below.

If you have private struct's methods implemented in more than one compilation unit you can still make it work by moving private's definition to a dedicated header:

```
// func_implementation.h
#include "func.h"
struct PRIVATE_NOT_ACCESSIBLE
{
    int i;
};
// internal methods, helper functions you don't want exposed should go here too.
// eg.
void helper_method(myint_t *);
```

Source files that implement your struct private 'object' will include 'func_implementation.h'. External client code that uses private will include 'func.h' only.

Comment: Thank you so much. That is really good. Another question is, is it possible to keep the `struct` definition in .h file or seperate .c file? The reason I'm asking is because `func2.c` needs to use the same `struct`.

Comment: Can you also please explain this line `struct PRIVATE_NOT_ACCESSIBLE;`? What exactly does?

Comment: @markfw that's a forward-declare for a struct. it's analogous to a function prototype. It tells the compiler 'hey this type exist somewhere, don't worry about it'.

Comment: Thank you. Since `func.c` and `func2.c` needs to use the same `struct`, is it possible to define that `struct` in another file .c? or .h? and use it?

Answer (score 5):

- You must end a `typedef` statement with a `;`
- `extern typedef` makes no sense, just do a `typedef`.

Comment: To elaborate, `typedef` is a storage class, similar to `extern` and `static`. The compiler complains that you are applying multiple storage classes to one definition.

Comment: @larsmans using `typedef` instead of `extern typedef` and removing `typedef` from `func.h` gives me a compile error in `func.h`: `expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm', or '__attribute__' before '*' token`

Comment: @markfw: after the edits, `PRIVATE_` is no longer visible in `func.h`. You need a `typedef struct _my_private_struct PRIVATE_;`

Comment: @larsmans: That would cause the redefinition of PRIVATE_?? I'm getting compile error: in `public.h: redefinition of typedef PRIVATE_` and in `func.h: previous decelaration of 'PRIVATE_' was here in file included from main.c`

Answer (score 2):

The current syntax is incorrect, you need to put a semicolon after the typedefs and the structs.

Answer (score 1):

There is a ';' missing after the typedef.

EDIT:

```
struct _my_private_struct {...};
```

Don't use names with a leading underscore. They are reserved for the language or the implementation.

Comment: Actually, names starting with two underscores or an underscore followed by a capital are reserved. Names with a single leading underscore can legitimately be used for "internal" use by libraries.